# How to check if TextBox + Textbox greater then or equal to an int

Tags: c#

I want to enable an button when the int in an textbox + an other int in an textbox = a specific number. (shown in code) So i want the program to check if the 2 ints in the textboxes are greater then or equal to. But i can not find a way how to do it. This it what i have so far

```
if ((TBoxGetZ.Text) ++ (TBoxZMove.Text)) >= 2 
{
    BtnUp.Enabled = false;
}
else
{
  BtnUp.Enabled = true;

}
```

Comment: you can convert the values in the textboxes to integers using the `int.Parse()` method and then perform the comparison.

Comment: Do you want to do this as the user is typing? If so, you'll need to subscribe to the `TextBox.TextChanged` event and in the handler do the parsing/comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The textboxes are strings, so you need to convert them to ints before you can compare.

```
//Convert to int, and only proceed if both are valid int values
if (int.TryParse(TBoxGetZ.Text, out var intValueFromTBoxGetZ) && int.TryParse(TBoxZMove.Text, out var intValueFromTBoxGetZ) )
{

    //Compare the values
    if (intValueFromTBoxGetZ + intValueFromTBoxGetZ >= 2)
    {
       BtnUp.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        BtnUp.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```